# Hangman recursive c#

Tags: c#, recursion

im trying to make a console application about hangman while using recursive function . i dont understand how i will make it happen without loops . i did it without recursive and it works fine , but i need to modify it into a recursive method , the following code is my non recursive code .

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string HiddenWord = "csharp";

        //--make a dash array
        char[] dashes = new char[HiddenWord.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < dashes.Length; i++)
        {
            dashes[i] = '_';
        }

        // --type dashes equal to array length
        for (int i = 0; i < dashes.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(dashes[i] + "  ");
        }


        Console.WriteLine();

        int count = 0;
        //--ask the user to guess
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
            char letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < HiddenWord.Length; i++)
            {
                //replace dash with letter
                if (HiddenWord[i] == letter)
                {
                    count++; //update the count to check when to exit
                    dashes[i] = letter;  //if correct letter put dash instead of letter

                    //display again dash with letters instead
                    for (int j = 0; j < dashes.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(dashes[j] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        } while (count < dashes.Length);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Why should it be recursive and what part do you want to make recursive? Doesn't the loop suffice? Why not?

Comment: `but i need to modify it into a recursive method`  who says?

Comment: probably the exercise sheet says so....

Comment: i have an exercise sheet exactly @PatrickHofman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this?

```
class Program
{
    static string HiddenWord = "";
    static char[] dashes;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HiddenWord = "csharp";
        dashes = new char[HiddenWord.Length];


        for (int i = 0; i < dashes.Length; i++)
        {
            dashes[i] = '_';
        }

        // --type dashes equal to array length
        for (int i = 0; i < dashes.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(dashes[i] + "  ");
        }


        Console.WriteLine();

        int count = 0;
        //--ask the user to guess
        askUserToGuess(count);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void askUserToGuess(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
        char letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < HiddenWord.Length; i++)
        {
            //replace dash with letter
            if ((HiddenWord[i] == letter) && (dashes[i] != letter))
            {
                count++; //update the count to check when to exit
                dashes[i] = letter;  //if correct letter put dash instead of letter

                //display again dash with letters instead
                for (int j = 0; j < dashes.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(dashes[j] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        if (count < dashes.Length) askUserToGuess(count);
    }
}
```

Near (HiddenWord[i] == letter) I've added another control (dashes[i] != letter) because if you hit 5times the "r" char (withouth check dashes[]) the program stop anyway

EDIT:

```
    class Program
{
    static string HiddenWord = "";
    static char[] dashes;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        HiddenWord = "csharp";
        dashes = new char[HiddenWord.Length];

        recursiveSetDashes(0);
        recursiveWriteDashes(0);
        Console.WriteLine();

        askUserToGuess(count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void recursiveWriteDashes(int v)
    {
        Console.Write(dashes[v] + "  ");
        v++; if (v < dashes.Length) recursiveWriteDashes(v);
    }

    private static void recursiveSetDashes(int i)
    {
        dashes[i] = '_';
        i++; if (i < dashes.Length) recursiveSetDashes(i);            
    }

    private static void askUserToGuess(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
        char letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        recursiveReplaceDashes(0,letter,ref count);

        if (count < dashes.Length) askUserToGuess(count);
    }

    private static void recursiveReplaceDashes(int v, char letter, ref int count)
    {
        if ((HiddenWord[v] == letter) && (dashes[v] != letter))
        {
            count++; dashes[v] = letter;  

            recursiveWriteDashes(0);
        }
        v++; if (v < dashes.Length) recursiveReplaceDashes(v, letter, ref count);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit , i see how you used recursion here but what ive been told is that it should work without for or while loops , which i couldnt find possible . is that possible u think ? @GMazzacua

Comment: Would you remove all for and all while? you could use different recursive function (but it's not a good solution).

Comment: @Rifai the recursion works without for or while loops, but you still need to loop through the `string` and `char[]`, or use `Linq` methods. But this does not necessarily mean that it is not recursive. The decisive point is the recursive call in the end!

Comment: well thats what the instructor wants , he specifically said without for and while loops.. i tried a lot but i couldnt find any solution and then i asked my question here .  @GMazzacua

Comment: aha thanks for the explanation  @MongZhu , i was really thinking about how could it work and how would i display it without loops , it just cant be as far as i know

Comment: @Rifai Edited... I hope it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

To stop a recursive method you need a condition. In your case you use it already:

```
} while (count < dashes.Length);
```

You need to build it inside your method, either in the beginning or in the end

EDIT: (I removed the old example, look in the previous edit if you need the code anyway)

The beauty of C# is that it is sometimes really intuitive. The condition to break the recursion can be formulated as: Execute code if **Any** dashes are left. There exist a method with the same name, and the `count` variable becomes obsolete. This way you also would avoid stopping the recursion falsely if the user types only the same letter too often. Here is a slightly shorter version of your code:

```
public static char[] recursive2(string HiddenWord, char[] dashes)
{
    // do only if the are Any dashes in the array
    if (dashes.Any(x=>x == '_'))
    {                
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter");
        char letter = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < HiddenWord.Length; i++)
        {
            //replace dash with letter
            //if correct letter put dash instead of letter ELSE put old character
            dashes[i] = HiddenWord[i] == letter ? letter : dashes[i];
        }

        //display again dash with letters instead
        Console.Write(String.Join(" ", dashes) + Environment.NewLine);

        // here happens the recursion! call the same method with the newly
        // changed parameters
        return recursive2(HiddenWord, dashes);
    }
    else
    {
        return "\nCongratulations!".ToCharArray();
    }
}
```

Here is how you can prepare the game and call the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string HiddenWord = "csharp";

    //--make a dash array
    char[] dashes = new String('_',HiddenWord.Length).ToCharArray();

    //display dash separated by spaces
    Console.Write(String.Join(" ", dashes) + Environment.NewLine);

    // Call the recursive method and when it breaks write "Congratulation" to the console
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", recursive2(HiddenWord, dashes)));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: thats good , but little complicated with advanced stuff , i need it simple because we are not that advanced in class yet and my teacher will probably fail me :)  .

Comment: hehe I thought so, but since we are here on SO to learn, I thought I give you this code. Your homework is your responsibility. ;-) the other code you can still find in the previous edit in the history. just click on "edited xx mins ago" below my post